# Laravel authentication redirecting locally

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have a site online which is authenticating fine. However first issue that I got when I pulled the site locally is that I got an error that view `home` was not found, which was obviously there.

After some research I ran the following commands:

```
artisan config:clear
artisan config:cache
artisan clear-compiled
artisan view:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

basically anything that could be cache related (though this is the only site where I need to do this once I pull it). And now views work perfectly.

But now the authentication doesn't work locally. When I enter credentials (and it IS pointing to the right record on existing local DB) I just get redirected back to the login page without errors.

Where can I even start with debugging on this issue?

Comment: So... you have errors or you don't have errors?

Comment: If I get redirected to page "without errors"...then I don't have them obviously :)

Comment: Not so obvious when you said "I got an error that view home was not found"

Comment: I would start from double-checking the .env file. After that maybe `dd()` some model data to make sure that everything is working as supposed. Then, I would check the routes (especially the auth routes)...

Comment: what is your local environment ? Are you using `Laravel Valet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to check these things :

• Did the laravel_session cookie is set on your browser ?

• Did the storage/framework/session is present and has it the correct right ?

If the above fail, try to intercept before the redirection to your protected page (since you have no error, Your application is correctly login you, redirect to your protected page, but then as your session / cookie is not set, the auth middleware is redirecting you on the connection page.

Then check if you have any full path in your config folder, and in your .env file

Comment: Both `APP_URL` and `SESSION_DOMAIN` had domain name written, so once I removed those I resolved the issue. Thanks